# Jpa, linked class take main class id

Tags: java, jpa

I have a Product :

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "products", schema = "laboratory", catalog = "laboratory")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    @Transient
    private Project project; // this one is for read only
    @Column(name="project_id") // this will save the id in db for the project
    private int projectId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private Inspection inspection;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private Information information;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private Departure departure;
    private String un;
    private String tc;
}
```

There is 3 class that this product needs in order to be a Product : `Information`, `Inpection`, `Departure`

All 3 of these classes are similar.
I want to link them by the `Product`.`id` witch is a `@GeneratedValue` AI in sql.

Here is one of the 3 class :
`Information`

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "products_informations", schema = "laboratory", catalog = "laboratory")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class Information {
    @Id
    private int productId;
    private String description;
    private String model;
    private int year;
    private String serialNumber;
    private int odometre;
    private int noCrochet;
    private int nbKeys;
    private String localisation;
    private String cemeteryPosition;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date receptionDate;
}
```

I want, WHEN I `save()` the product, that the `private String productId` in this class to automatically take the Id from the `Product` class without having to do it manually in my controller.

Comment: That's not possible

Comment: So, in my request, I have to mannually put `{product: {information: {productId: THE_ID}}}` and repeat it for all 3 classes In order to make it work ?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli there sure is a way, because the product `id` is auto increment, there is no way to set it to the sub classes before the `save()`

Comment: You don't have to transfer it. But you have to set it before calling save. You can use getReference to not access the database https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getReferenceById-ID-

Comment: I dont have the entityManager, I use `Crud` @SimonMartinelli

Comment: What is Crud???

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html @SimonMartinelli

Comment: Then simply use JpaRepository instead

Comment: @SimonMartinelli this is not the anwser I need

Comment: But that's the way it would work without affecting performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the mappings backwards in your model.

By using

```
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private Information information;
```

You've told JPA to use the PRODUCT.ID primary key as a foreign key to the Information table; foreign keys are controlled by the relationship, so it means your ID value is pulled from the information.productId value. Opposite of what you are asking for and it means you have 4 mappings trying to set the PRODUCT.ID column value (set them different and see for yourself).

Try this instead:

```
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(mappedby="product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Information information;
    ..
}

public class Information {
    @Id
    private int productId;
    @MapsId
    private Product product;
    ..
}
```

With this you will need to set the Information.product reference, but JPA will use that to set your productId value, using the one you set within the product.id property. You just need to set this relationship when you add an Information instance to a product. Do the same for the other relationships

Comment: Thanks, as you said, I had to set the product inside `Information` in the `Product` constructor.